# How access from UI to DataAccess Objects? Using 3 name space

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout, interface, asp.net-mvc-layout

I am a bit new to using several Classes in a single project. I have a project which include 3 projects. first is my mvc layout 2nd is BL and 3rd is DL. mvc has a reference to bl and bl to dl. Now the problem is here , how can I access from mvc to dl objects? am I should using Interfaces? I have an enum in dl which is like that:

```
namespace AccounterDL
{


    public enum Sort
    {
        None = 0,
        Descending,
        Assending


    }



}
```

Now I can't access to this from mvc contorller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AccounterBL;
using PagedList;
//using AccounterDL;  I don't want get it directly








namespace AccounerTransactions.Controllers
{
//sort s ...
}
```

I want skip Data Access from mvc and get object from bl while its in dl...

Comment: It depends on what the pattern is that you're following. Do you want to hide the data layer behind the business logic layer? if so, a direct reference from your presentation layer to your data layer may not be what you want. Otherwise, if it matters not to you, then why not add a reference to the data layer from the presentation layer?

Answer (score -1):

You should add DL reference to mvc project then take DL namespace

build dl assembly then add to mvc project

Comment: I don't want to Get it directly.